# Tutorial on performance analysis of pig and hive scripts

Tags: performance, hadoop, hive, apache-pig

I am looking for good tutorials on doing performance analysis and improvement of pig latin scripts and hive scripts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any such tutorial. The only **good** way in my view is to do it yourself keeping your data and your case in mind.

Having said that, you can make use of something like **[TPC-H](http://www.tpc.org/tpch/)** to benchmark your queries and based on the results you can improve and optimize your Pig and Hive queries, in case you find some performance bottlenecks. This will also help you in figuring out what Pig and Hive are not good at. Also, you can compare both the tools in case your are confused which one to go for for a particular task.

You can find more on this by visiting the below specified links :

- **Running TPC-H Benchmark on Pig [Ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2397)**.
- **Running TPC-H Benchmark on Pig [Ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-600)**.

And if you need all the details, you can visit the original papers on **Running TPC-H on [Pig](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~jieli/cps216_group1_prj2_pig_tpch.pdf) and [Hive](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12416257/TPC-H_on_Hive_2009-08-11.pdf)**. These papers contain great deal of information and you will definitely find them helpful during the process.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's what you're looking for but Big Data University has some pretty good tutorials on Hive and Pig. Give it a shot. You'll need the IBM QuickStart VM. Its a huge download but its free and pretty good.

Link:
http://www-01.ibm.com/software/data/infosphere/biginsights/quick-start/

There's tutorials on the VM as well that are pretty good but i think the ones at BigDataUni are better.

In case it matters, I registered on both websites and haven't gotten any spam or anything.